# How to display a resource from a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I'm creating a mostly static home page for a website, except for one little container that needs to pull web links from a model database. The home page view is sitting in `home_controller` which I created earlier in development. I've now created the `link` resource and `links_controller`.

I don't know much about rails and what I've been doing up to now is displaying resources in the index view for their designated controller. However, i need to display this resource in the index view for the home_controller.

Can someone guide me in the right direction towards doing this?

Comment: you might be looking for render or redirect? from the sound of it redirect might be what you are looking for or maybe what you want is to move some relevant bits into a partial and simply render that partial on both pages?  (note that render in the controller is different from render in the views)... your question needs more context... it might help if you included your controllers and relevant views...

Comment: i have two controllers, the `home_controller` and the `links_controller`. The home controller just has one view, `index`. I also have another controller, `links_controller` that manages the REST behind the model db for links. I need to display these links in the index view of the `home_controller`, and don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a query to fetch the required link objects in the `index` action of `home_controller` and display it in the view, as you want:

```
# HomeController

def index
  # other code
  # @links = Link.all  # or any other query you may want to do
end

# in the view index.html.erb
<% @links.each do |link| %>
<%= link.url %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Customize it as per your needs.

Comment: Awesome. I did not think it was this simple. Thank you.